# Yii - How do a make a link with a class if the current page is the same of the link?

Tags: php, yii

For example, I have this structure :

```
<div id="menuPainelSuperior">
 <a href="<?= CController::createUrl('site/seu_cadastro')?>">Cadastro</a>
 <a href="<?= CController::createUrl('site/lista_clientes') ?>">Clientes</a>
 <a href="<?= CController::createUrl('site/projetos') ?>">Projetos</a>
 <a href="<?= CController::createUrl('site/orcamentos') ?>">Orçamentos</a>
</div>
```

if the current page is "domain.com/site/seu_cadastro" I want the first link then to have the following class : "activePageMenu"

Do anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put an if statement on the link to see if the current controller and action is the same as the controller and action you are putting in the link. You get them like this:

```
$controller = Yii::app()->controller->id;
$action =  Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
$class = '';
if($controller == 'site' && $action == 'seu_cadastro') $class = 'activePageMenu';
echo CHtml::link('Cadastro',array('site/seu_cadastro'),array('class'=>$class));
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted !! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the build in [CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu/) to do this??

**Update:** Pitchinnate's answer is also a way to do that.

Comment: I support this answer to use CMenu as it have more features and its designed for this kind of cases. +1